# How to reuse last input in command with a prompt?

Tags: interactive, commands, history-variables

Some existing functions have ability to remember last input, which you can use in the next command call - for example, `replace-string` will suggest the last replacement by default, while `isearch` will look for the thing you searched for last, after pressing the combination once again. How can I achieve the same effect as in `replace-string`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `read-string` and give they default value `def-say-word` and save in later.

```
(setq def-say-word "default value")

(defun say-word (word)
  (interactive
   (list (read-string (format "Say word [%s]: " def-say-word) nil nil def-say-word)))
   (setq def-say-word word)
   (message "The word is %s" word))
```

Answer (score 4):

Commands that read input from the minibuffer use functions such as `completing-read`, `read-string`, `read-regexp`, etc. The most general of these is `read-from-minibuffer`.

All such functions take a `HISTORY` argument, which is a variable whose value is a list of previous inputs read by the function.  If `HISTORY` is absent or `nil` then usually the variable is understood to be `minibuffer-history`.

So you just provide the variable you want, to get the behavior you want.

As a user, to get to previous inputs when reading a new input, you use **`M-p`** (or `M-n`), which you can repeat to go farther back in the given history list.  Or you can use **`M-r`** (or `M-s`) to search the history list for a match to a regular expression that you type at the prompt.

See the Emacs manual, node [Minibuffer History](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minibuffer-History.html) and the Elisp manual, node [Minibuffer History](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Minibuffer-History.html).

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. However, I wanted to provide default value, and I wanted to explicitly tell user about it. Konstantin's answer does that.

Comment: All of the functions I mentioned accept a `DEFAULT-VALUE` argument. And there is no need to "save" it in a global variable, for the reason I already gave: it is available in the history list (variable) that you also pass to the function. (And if you do use a global variable for that, for some reason, you should use `defvar`, not just `setq`.)

Comment: Example then, please?

Comment: Example of what? Passing a `DEFAULT` argument to `read-string` or `completing-read` or whatever? Or getting values from a given `HISTORY` argument list value? Or using `defvar` instead of `setq`? What is your remaining question, exactly?

Comment: Example of applying your solution to solve my problem. I tried what you're suggesting and none of the behaviours is the one I want; I'd like to present the user with option to just press enter to get the default value used(and inform about the default value somehow in the prompt), instead of providing history. I asked for the same behaviour as in replace-string. None of your suggestions provide that behaviour.

Comment: Each of the functions I mentioned accepts a default value. It is shown in the prompt. And the user can accept it simply by hitting `RET` ("Enter"). You don't need to access the history unless you want to get to *previous* inputs. If you just want to get the current default then just hit `RET`. Provide a step-by-step recipe to show what you want, if this is not it, as this corresponds exactly to your description. Start by consulting the doc I pointed you to. It's pretty straightforward, really.

Comment: Run `replace-string a b` and then `replace-string` to see what I mean - I don't want the value to wait there in input field, I don't want it to be hidden in the history - I want to be default after hitting RET, and user to be informed. Honestly I don't know how I can be misunderstood when the first guy understood me, and at the very end I specify that I want precisely the behaviour of other command. Do you know how `replace-string` works?

Comment: "*Do you know how replace-string works?*" Yes, I do. Do *you*? It ultimately uses `read-regexp` or `read-from-minibuffer` to read your input, in each case providing a default value, which is **shown in the prompt**. The point of my answer was to inform you about these basic functions that read input, accept a default value and a history variable, and show the default in the prompt. `replace-string` is one such command that fits the first sentence of this answer.

Comment: I'm not sure we understand each other, and comments aren't the best way to communicate. I suggest we take this conversation [to the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42472/emacs-question-about-interactive-input-chat).

Comment: Sorry, but I'm afraid I don't have anything more to say about this. If what I've offered helps, great. If not, sorry about that.